# No module named 'classification'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, module

python3 version 3.6.9
tensorflow version 1.14.0
Ubuntu 18.04.4

I am currently trying the tutorial of Coral Dev Board on retraining a classification with weight imprinting. (https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-classification-ondevice/ ) After reaching Step 3 of "Pre-train the model", I tried to modify to train which suit my directory.

```
python3 mobilenet_v1_l2norm_train.py \
--quantize=True \
--dataset_dir=/home/edgetpu/img_classify/flowers \
--fine_tune_checkpoint=/home/edgetpu/img_classify/train/model.ckpt-300 \
--checkpoint_dir=/home/edgetpu/l2norm-training \
--freeze_base_model=True \
--number_of_steps=100000
```

However, even if I try to add `--classification=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/classification` at the end of code, I still got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification'
```

I have no idea where the classification module is. `pip install classification` and trying training directly on board also do not work. Please help.

Comment: maybe ```classification``` is a python file in the source. In case its in a folder, you need to put an empty ```__init__.py``` file in that folder to import that as a module.

Comment: classification folder originally exist in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/classification with _init_.py, but it seems it cannot be recognised?
```File "/home/carl/edgetpu/imprinting-training/classification/mobilenet_v1_l2norm.py", line 23, in <module>

    from classification import conv2d_l2norm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classification'
```